# Receiving url from the curl source

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple question to ask. I am using CURL to send data using post fields to my destination server. I am using the following code,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postStr);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And then i am capturing the data using

```
$post = $_POST;
```

So is there anyway i can determine from which server the curl data is coming from? Since its coming from 5 different servers. I want to capture the URL of the source from which postfields are being sent. Thanks

Comment: Well, you could add an identifier to the post data, that is a typical solution. Some may also say you can evaluate the senders ip address, but that often does not work, for example when proxies and NAT comes into play.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by capturing the URL. Is it different than ***$url***?

Comment: Not every PHP script necessarily has an URL. And curl wouldn't implicitly send one along. You could manually add a POST field that identifies the origin server, introduce an "API key", or else use the `REMOTE_ADDR`. Depends on if this is just meant for statistics, as decoration, or needed for authorization-like purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the verbose mode (-v) on the cURL program.

Example:

```
C:\curl www.google.com

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=Y76WVbuaAvGp8wf42oGADw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Or:

```
C:\curl -v www.google.com

* Rebuilt URL to: www.google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.222.4... <<< ---     <<< ---    YOUR SERVER IS THIS ONE
* Connected to www.google.com (216.58.222.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.0
> Accept: * / * <
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: http://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=A76WVZvWCO-p8wf334HIDg
< Content-Length: 262
< Date: Fri, 03 Jul 2015 16:53:23 GMT
< Server: GFE/2.0
< Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0
<
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=A76WVZvWCO-p8wf334HIDg">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
```